# Wordpress Pagination - 301 Redirect Issue

Tags: redirect, pagination

[image]I have this wordpress problem with pagination and redirects.
Let's take this scenario - I have a blog on my website and it has a lot of articles, therefore the blog expands to /page-35/.

Let's say that I redirect one blog article from /blog-article/ to /blog-article-2/.

When I search the blog for that article in the paginated series, let's say it appears on /page-6/ it will appear in the snippet as /blog-article/, not the new version of the url, causing a 301 redirect.

So, is there a way to stop this from happening?

I hope I've explained it clearly enough and sorry if this is a common topic, but I didn't know how to search for this issue I'm having.

Comment: can you explain using different words what you meant by "therefore the blog expands to /page-35/."? How are you implementing redirects? Can you use full URL examples so that it's clearer? You can use `example.com` as the domain if you don't want to share a production sites URL. How is your pagination implemented?

Comment: That was an example to emphasize that the blog has many pages - like example.com/blog/page-35/. In this pages articles are shown with feature image, a clickable title and a read more link. On the clickable title and the read more link it will show the old version of the url, not the new one if I decide to change it. Does this clear it up? Also I've added an image from a random blog to let you know exactly where on the page this problem occurs. WP always redirects to the canonical URL which is best practice

Comment: oooh, you've muddled up rewrites and redirects. I do not know how you have implemented redirects, but a redirect does not change the URL of a post, it just redirects you to that post. Think of it like the difference between moving to a new house, versus installing a sign at the new house that leads to your old house, the sign is the redirect. Posts have 1 canonical URL, you should change the permalinks etc to match that desired single unique URL, then redirect to that. Your redirect should not be that canonical URL. If you have more than one URL then you will face SEO penalties

Comment: Don't think I understand so I'm going to explain the process, maybe it will help. So, for redirects I use Yoast. In terms of canonical, all urls have self canonical, so when I redirect example.com/old-article/ to example.com/new-article/ the canonical for example.com/new-article/ it's itself. After I complete the redirect, I crawl the website to find where the old url is linked internally and replace it. I can replace if it's content, if it's in the menu or footer, but I cannot replace it when it's in the blog pagination as shown above.

Comment: that sounds like a Yoast SEO problem, not a WordPress problem, have you contacted their support or asked in a Yoast SEO community? 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here and not in this stacks scope.

Answer (score 0):

Are your /old-article/ and /new-article/ posts both separate WordPress posts? If they are separate (published) posts, and all you've done is redirect /old-article/ to /new-article/, then as far as WordPress knows, both posts are still published in the backend, therefore both /old-article/ and /new-article/ will show in the blog feed, regardless of the redirects. You have to draft or delete your /old-article/, OR change the permalink on /old-article/ to /new-article/. Otherwise, it will still show in your blog feed.